# How to add a certain height for sticky menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://www.mysecretathens.gr/kulte_test/docrads.html

I want to achieve a sticky menu effect at a CERTAIN height for the #nav menu. Something like tha: http://www.snogglemedia.com/- where the sidebar menu sticks at a certain height. Can I do that with css and how? Or is it only possible with jquery?

Comment: You are referring to "Affixing" a menu vertically, if I am reading your question correctly.  This is achieved using both CSS and jQuery/Javascript.  If you do not need the menu to ever scroll, you can achieve it by using CSS, see my answer below.

Comment: Furthermore, you can see it in action at the Twitter Bootstrap page (and many, many others) at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html.

Answer (score 0):

If the menu never needs to scroll at all, you can achieve the effect using pure CSS.  You will add the following CSS to the element:

```
<div id="vertMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>First Item</li>
        <li>Second Item</li>
        <li>Third Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

div#vertMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 25px;
}
```

Of course you will need to use your own Top & Left values depending on the placement you want; however, the Absolute positioning will keep your DIV in place.

Comment: If you need your menu to scroll with your page to a "certain" place, then stick there, it is called Affixing and you will need to use jQuery to toggle CSS classes.